# Check If the user click save or cancel button when downloading file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, download

I already have the functionality to download the file.

```
    public ActionResult Download(Guid AuthKey)
    {

        FileContentResult file = new FileContentResult(dataSet.Document, "Application/pdf");
        Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dataSet.DocumentName + ".pdf");
        return file;
    }
```

How can i check if the user click the save button or cancel button on the download dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture this event. The way the download dialog is implemented might vary between browsers. There is nothing in the HTML specification that says how it should look like. In some browsers there might not even be a download dialog box. There might not even be Save or Cancel buttons.

Comment: Thanks Darin, do you have any idea about this?
So in this situtation, i need to insert the record on table once the user click save button. if the user clicks the cancel button, I should not insert the records.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do that before calling the action. Like you have dialog with like download and cancel button. That way you can have the intentions of the user. If he click download he means downloading otherwise dont call the action.

Comment: Liked this approach... the dialog with Download / Cancel buttons could have some preview information of your document. Later you could add extra features like "Send by email" button. That way your confirmation dialog is not so empty.  If you are counting downloads (some quota), in this dialog you could explain that hitting download will count as a download even if he cancel the process later.